# Interpretation of ARIMA (2,0,0)

Tags: r, arima, interpretation, autoregressive

I have a very small dataset and worked with the auto.arima()function to forecast data.
I went as follows:

1. removed outliers

```r
###remove outlier 2004, 2009
Dr_ts_1 <- ts(Dr_ts[-c(10,16)], start = 1994, end = 2019) 
plot.ts(Dr_ts_1)
```

2. checked for stationarity & to reach it I had to use second-order differentiation.

```r
### convert data into stationarity
Dr_ts_dif_1 <- diff(Dr_ts_1)
plot(Dr_ts_dif_1)
### check for stationarity
adf.test(Dr_ts_dif_1)
### not stationary, second order differenciation
Dr_ts_dif_1<- diff(Dr_ts_1, differences  = 2)
plot(Dr_ts_dif_1)
### check for stationarity
adf.test(Dr_ts_dif_1)
```

3. Used the auto.arima() function on my differentiated data set, the best fitting model would be (2,0,0)
4. Used the box-pierce test to check the model
5. forecast

Now my model looks like this:

```r
arima(x = Dr_ts_dif_1, order = c(2, 0, 0))

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2  intercept
      -1.0978  -0.5957    -0.0003
s.e.   0.1581   0.1646     0.0012

sigma^2 estimated as 0.00024:  log likelihood = 65.21,  aic = -122.41
```

I do not know what this tells me or how to interpret this. I am interested in the forecasted values and their trend - but I removed that when I differentiated twice to reach stationarity. So my question would be how to interpret these data, and how I can interpret these data especially keeping in mind, that the not stationary data which I then differentiated do display a trend.

Edit 1: I changed the way I removed outliers & am now replacing them with `NA`. Instead of differencing first, I included a second order difference in the arima model which is now (2,2,0). Would that modelling be the correct approach?

Comment: A `ts` object is always regularly sampled, so it seems like in your first step `Dr_ts_1` will be mislabeled by "removing" outliers in this way (e.g. it will have an observation labelled 2004 that is actually 2005). You can replace those values by `NA`, or use exogenous dummy variables instead. Also, you don't need to difference first, you can just include a difference in the ARIMA model, that way the forecast will already be on the level scale.

Comment: Maybe edit your post to reflect your changes in analysis, removing completely the older oarts! That is much better than just a note at the end.